# Form that triggers setTimeout + window.open javascript and newtab?

Tags: javascript

Hi friends I have a simple form and I need the quoted javascript to open newwindow with setTimout of 3 seconds on button submit action + new tabright in same window. The problem is that the code needs to bypass the browsers popup blocker. Simple words, when a user click on the button of the form to see newtab right in same window and after 3 seconds delay to see newwindow which is not blocked by the browser popup blocker. You can modify the script as it is for standalone action and right now the browser always blocks the popup from it.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeout(myFunction, 3 * 1000);
});

function myFunction() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('3125') >= -1) {
    window.open('http://example.com/page_3125', 'mywindow2', 'width=1600,height=1200');
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="form-register" method="get" onsubmit="myFunction(this);" action "http://somesite.com/" target="_blank">
  <div class="form-row">
    <button type="submit">Continue</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think the browser blocks your popup because the event is set to the body.

Comment: Yes that's why I need the script to run after a click on the button of the form so it is treated as human action. Do you have any recommendations for same results?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't *simulate* human action. That is all what the blocking is about. If that was possible, the block would be useless, agree?

Comment: Yes but it is a human action to click on a button which opens the popup with 3 seconds delay? Is it possible to do it that way as I asked?